# Hide data source path

Tags: excel, powerquery

I pull data from sql server to excel for my reports. Now I have to share those workbooks with other users. My question is how can I hide data source path change name in query settings?I used protect workbook and worksheet but it only help with disabling editin queries. But I don't want my server and database name to be visible. can anyone help me to find a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the data source in Power Query via the query's privacy settings.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/privacy-levels-power-query-cc3ede4d-359e-4b28-bc72-9bee7900b540

From the link above:

- ***Private data source*** - A Private data source contains sensitive or confidential information, and the **visibility of the data source may be restricted to authorized users**. A private data source is completely isolated from other data sources.

- ***Organizational data source*** - An Organizational data source **limits the visibility of a data source to a trusted group of people**. An Organizational data source is isolated from all Public data sources, but is visible to other Organizational data sources.